# If $G$ is order $p^2q$, where $p$, $q$ are primes, prove that either a Sylow $p$-subgroup or a Sylow $q$-subgroup must be normal in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

If $G$ is order $p^2q$, where $p$, $q$ are primes, prove that either a Sylow $p$-subgroup or a Sylow $q$-subgroup must be normal in $G$.

Comment: What have you tried/what do you know so far?

Comment: Abishek, welcome to Math StackExchange! Good question but you should display some efforts of your own, show what you know and in what direction your are thinking. Otherwise people will close your post. Also browse this site for the answer, since what I remember this question has been asked here before.

Answer (score 0):

> **(Sylow).** Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^km$ with $p\nmid m$, and $r$ be the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Then (1) every Sylow $p$-subgroup is conjugate to one Sylow $p$-subgroup. (2) $r\mid m$ and $r\equiv1\pmod p$.

In this case, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, say $r_1$, satisfies $r_1\mid q$ and $r_1\equiv1\pmod p$, but $q$ is a prime, so $r_1=1$ or $r_1=q$. If $r_1=1$, then there is unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, and it is normal. Otherwise $q=r_1\equiv1\pmod p$, and let $r_2$ be the number of Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. Still we have $r_2\mid p^2$ and $r_2\equiv1\pmod q$. If $r_2=p^2$, then $r_2\equiv1\pmod q$ implies $p\equiv\pm1\pmod q$. This contradicts $q\equiv1\pmod p$. Similarly $r_2\ne p$, so we have $r_2=1$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Case $(1)$ If $p \gt q$, then a  Sylow $p$ subgroup of order $p^2$ would have index $q$ which is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ , hence the Sylow $p$ subgroup would be normal.

Case $(2)$  If $q\gt p^2$ , then the only allowed no. of Sylow $q$ subgroups is $1$ since $qk+1\gt p^2$ for $p\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the Sylow $q$ subgroup is normal.

Case $(3)$ If $p\lt q\lt p^2$.

Let us assume that the neither the Sylow $p$ subgroup nor Sylow $q$ subgroup are unique.

Then the no. of Sylow $q$ subgroup must be $p^2$ since the divisors of $p^2$ are $1,p,p^2$.

Any two of these $p^2$ Sylow $q$ subgroups must have trivial intersection , since the non-trivial elements of a group of prime order will generate the whole group.

Hence  total no. of elements in all of these Sylow $q$ subgroups$=p^2(q-1)+1 \quad (*)$

Now, let $P_1, P_2$ be two different Sylow $p$  subgroups.

So we must have ,

$P_1\setminus P_2 \neq \emptyset$

Now, a Sylow $p$ subgroup and Sylow $q$ subgroup will intersect trivially since order of every element in the intersection will divide $p^2$ and $q$ which are relatively prime.

Adding the elements of $P_2$ (except the identity) to the total counting of elements of Sylow $q$ subgroups in $(*)$  , we must have total no. of elements

$=p^2q-p^2+1+p^2-1=p^2q$

But how to accomodate the elements of $P_1\setminus P_2$  in a group of order $p^2q$ with the above counting of elements.

So our assumotion is wrong, one of the Sylow subgroups must be unique and hence normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplement to user735332's answer.

First notice that $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ implies $p<q$.

Then consider the case $r_2=p^2$, sure it has the contradiction if $p\equiv 1\pmod q$, since it implies $p=1$, which contradicts that $p$ is prime. However, if $p\equiv -1\pmod q$, then $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ can not lead to contradiction, since $p=2$ and $q=3$ is a counterexample. Although that, the contradiction still holds except such case, since $p\equiv -1\pmod q$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ implies $p=q-1$, $p$ and $q$ are both prime, so we just need to check that the case $p=2$ and $q=3$ still leads to contradiction. For the case $p=2$ and $q=3$, we have $r_1=3$ and $r_2=4$, which mean that there are $4$ subgroup with order $3$ and $3$ subgroup with order $4$, inplies that there are at least $1+4*(3-1)+3*(4-1)=18$ elements in $G$, which contradicts that order of $G$ is $12$. Hence, we done the contradiction for the case $r_2=p^2$.